# RubyMotion Firebase (motion-firebase) How to query a single key

Tags: ios, firebase, rubymotion

I've been using

```
firebase.once(:value) { |snapshot| }
```

to query my data to this point. But now there's a serious performance issue as my data set is getting bigger.

I already know what keys I need to query, I'd rather just loop through a hand full of calls to Firebase to grab the values of the keys I need.

I'm looking for the appropriate [motion-firebase](https://github.com/colinta/motion-firebase) call to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I realize that it's not the Firebase call that is slow, it's the operations I'm doing on the data set once I've got it.

But wonder if an answer to this question may still be helpful to others?

Comment: Not without a lot more context. E.g.: what is the `firebase` referencing? What is "a serious performance issue"? What is your dataset structured like? Without adding that type of information to your question, I doubt it'll help many people (even if only because they'll never find it).

Comment: Firebase is a BAAS that I'm using as my database. My dataset looks like: {"key"=>{"key"=>"val", ... }, ...}. In my above comment I made reference to incorrectly identifying Firebase as the performance issue. Although I know what I have to do for my case, I'm leaving this question open in case someone actually wants to make a call to the Firebase API using motion-firebase with a query containing a single key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a new Firebase reference that points to that key or URL.

```rb
firebase = Firebase.new(YOUR_FIREBASE_URL)
keys = ["key1", "key2"]

keys.each do |key|
  firebase[key].once(:value) do |snapshot|
    puts "#{key} is now #{snapshot.val}"
  end
end
```

The important bit there is `firebase[key]`, which is a shorthand for the SDK method `firebase.childByAppendingPath(key)` (`firebase.child(key)` does the same thing).